# DirectX11 - Matrix Translation

Tags: translation, directx-11, transpose, d3dx

I am creating a 3D scene and I have just inserted a cube object into it. It is rendered fine at the origin but when I try to rotate it and then translate it I get a huge deformed cube. Here is the problem area in my code:

```
D3DXMATRIX cubeROT, cubeMOVE;

D3DXMatrixRotationY(&cubeROT, D3DXToRadian(45.0f));
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&cubeMOVE, 10.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);

D3DXMatrixTranspose(&worldMatrix, &(cubeROT * cubeMOVE));

// Put the model vertex and index buffers on the graphics pipeline to prepare them for drawing.
m_Model->Render(m_Direct3D->GetDeviceContext());

// Render the model using the light shader.
result = m_LightShader->Render(m_Direct3D->GetDeviceContext(), m_Model->GetIndexCount(), worldMatrix, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix, 
                   m_Model->GetTexture(), m_Light->GetDirection(), m_Light->GetDiffuseColor());


// Reset the world matrix.
m_Direct3D->GetWorldMatrix(worldMatrix);
```

I have discovered that it's the cubeMOVE part of the transpose that is giving me the problem but I have no idea why.

This rotates the cube properly:

```
D3DXMatrixTranspose(&worldMatrix, &cubeROT);
```

This translates the cube properly:

```
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&worldMatrix, 10.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);
```

But this creates the deformed mesh:

```
D3DXMatrixTranspose(&worldMatrix, &cubeMOVE);
```

I'm quite new to DirectX so any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think [`transpose`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) does what you think it does.  To combine transformation matrices, you just multiply them -- no need to transpose.  I guess it should be simply:

```
worldMatrix = cubeROT * cubeMOVE;
```

**Edit**

The reason "transpose" seems to work for rotation but not translation, is that transpose flips the non-diagonal parts of the matrix.  But for an [axis-rotation matrix](http://inside.mines.edu/fs_home/gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/), that leaves the matrix nearly unchanged.  (It does change a couple of signs, but that would only affect the direction of the rotation.)  For a translation matrix, applying a transpose would completely deform it -- hence the result you see.

Comment: Completely right. I was using D3DXMatrixTranspose instead of D3DXMatrixMultiply, thank you!